# Cascade Restriction with Soft Delete

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I looking for a solution to solve on delete cascade behavior. I'm using soft delete approach with EF Plus lib for setup filtering nothing special about that, standard EF Core filters. 
I also have entity (Invoice) with dependencies (VATType). I need to restrict deletion of VATType in case of we have active(not deleted) Invoice that has relation with VATType. 
In EF core without "softdelete" I can rely on SQL Server mechanism by applying for example this:
modelBuilder.Entity.HasOne(x => x.VatType).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

But with soft delete we just mark record as deleted by updating IsDelete column. And that will not work.

Is there any existing solution to solve this?

Comment: EF Core has no build-in congifueration to implement Cascade Restriction with Soft Delete , and the specific implementation needs to be determined according to your specific needs. What is you want to use soft delete in , dependent entity or all of principal entity and dependent entity ?

Comment: Principal. I don’t want to allow delete principal in case it has active relations

Comment: Cascade delete is mainly used to decide the effect on dependent entities when deleting principal entity . If you want to implement the soft delete on principal entity , you could override the `SaveChanges` method  refer to https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/01/29/entity-framework-core-soft-delete/